# When I click on a image it pop's out, but I want to blur the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my school project I'm making a website that contains a interactive sneakerwall.

The idea is that you can pick a shoe and it pop's out and gives you some information. On second click it goes back to where it was.

To give you an idea here's a picture of the website: [Shoe-wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcuC7.jpg)

So all the shoes are different images in my HTML, like this:

```
<div id="S-222" class="schoen"><img src="schoenenuitgeknipt\airmax97gr.png" ></div>
```

And for the background I have used this:

```
body{
  background: url("picturesari/bgari.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 98%;
}
```

So the code for popping up the shoe is as following:

```
<script>
var lastShoe = null,
  lastShoeTop, lastShoeLeft, lastShoeWidth, lastShoeHeight;
$('.schoen').click(function() {
  var tar = $(this)
  if (lastShoe != null) {
    lastShoe.fadeIn().animate({
      top: lastShoeTop,
      left: lastShoeLeft,
      height: lastShoeWidth,
      width: lastShoeHeight,
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      queue: false
    });
  }
  if (!tar.is(lastShoe)) {
    lastShoe = tar;
    lastShoeTop = lastShoe.position().top;
    lastShoeLeft = lastShoe.position().left;
    lastShoeWidth = lastShoe.width();
    lastShoeHeight = lastShoe.height();
    tar.fadeIn().animate({
      top: "10%",
      left: "30%",
      height: '+=570px',
      width: '+=374px',
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      queue: false
    });
  } else {
    lastShoe = null;
  }
});
</script>
```

**The question is:**

*How do I blur out the background and all the other shoes withouth blurring the one that is clicked*

Comment: There is not enought code to correctly recreate any issue, which is not clearly defined, by the way. Questions on SO have to be minimal... But also complete. Have a look at [**this CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dJVNJZ) and complete it in order to reflect the behavior you currently have. And refine your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Allright, I see in the CodePen that the shoes are on top of eachother.
Now mine are in one line but when I click 1 shoe i want the rest to be blurred with the background together.

Comment: I guess you udtated it... So what is the new link?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Arianitooo/pen/RxLpad

So I have no clue how to start with it. I just want all to be blurred + background, except for the clicked one. When i click again the blur goes away

Comment: You could probably do something with applying a [CSS filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) with blur on everything but the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay... Let talk about the changes made here.

**About the background:** I think it is better to use an `<img>` element with `position:fixed`, instead of the body background attribute.

Why? Exactly because when you want to add an effect on it, you can address the element **only* instead of the `<body>` which contains everything. This way, there is no inheritance (property passed to a child by default) an not a single effect on the other elements.

**About your use of `.animate()`** and your attempt to "measure" `height`, `width` and the top/left `position`. It was quite good. But when dealing with delays like with `.animate()`, it can be a mess. And that's what was happening with your posted code. The images did not always get their original size.

When you can use CSS instead of jQuery `.animate()`, do it! It's more efficient! There is absolutely no need to store the "original size and position. It's just a matter of adding or removing a class. Waaay more simple. ;)

So here is the code I made for you (and your homework!), please take the time to analyse it and be sure to understand it all before submitting it in class.

You can ask me some questions... But first, at least read those documentations:

**CSS:** [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

**jQuery:** [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**JavaScript:** [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Knowing the tools helps working better.

**script:**

```
var lastShoe = null;

// On click anywhere but not on a shoe
$(document).on("click",function(e){
  if( !$(e.target).parent("div").is(".schoen") ){
    $(".back, .schoen").removeClass("blurred displayPos");
  }
});

// On click on a shoe
$(".schoen").click(function() {
  $(".back").addClass("blurred");
  $(".schoen").removeClass("blurred");
  $(".schoen").not($(this)).addClass("blurred");

  // if the click occured on a different shoe than previous.
  if( !($(this).is(lastShoe)) ){
    lastShoe = $(this);
    $(".schoen").removeClass("displayPos");
    $(this).addClass("displayPos");
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.back{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.blurred{
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.displayPos{
  top:10% !important;
  left:30% !important;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.schoen{
  position:fixed;
  max-width:200px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.schoen img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OzxpRL?editors=1111)

Comment: Sir you are my hero! this is very clear to me and you have learned me some new things I thank you alot!!!

Answer (score -2):

You could select the images by class name and loop through them where you can apply the css blure property to them.

Comment: That is more a comment than an answer... Don't use the answer system to comment please. When you'll have 50 rep., you'll have the priviledge to comment.